# explanation of the output of the given question

Tags: python-3.x

In the displayed code the `val` variable has value `ar[0]` that is 10. But after 1 iteration of the for loop the value of `val` changes. Why does it change? This happens for all the iterations.

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

n = int(input())
ar = list(map(int,input().split()))
#print(len(ar))
while len(ar)!=0:
    val=ar[0]
    #print(val)
    #ar.remove(val)
    #print(ar)
    for val in ar:
        print(val)
        ar.remove(val)
        print(ar)

> 10 [30, 20, 10, 10, 20, 50, 10, 20] 
> 20 [30, 10, 10, 20, 50, 10, 20]  
> 10 [30, 10, 20, 50, 10, 20]
> 50 [30,10, 20, 10, 20]
> 20 [30, 10, 10, 20]
> 30 [10, 10, 20]
> 10 [10, 20]
> 10 [20]
> 20 []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are happening in your snippet that could potentially be confusing.

The first thing is you set `val=ar[0]` and then use it in the for-loop:

```
val=ar[0]
for val in ar:
    print(val)
```

As a result, val gets reassigned on every for-loop iteration.

The second thing that could be confusing, is the `ar.remove(val)` in the for-loop. Because you are removing while iterating, this could result in unspecified behavior.

To get the output you need, it would be best to implement the code using an additional auxiliary list:

```
ar = list(map(int,input().split()))
new_ar[:] = ar
while len(ar)!=0:
    for val in ar:
        print(val)
        new_ar.remove(val)
        print(new_ar)
```

it's not perfectly clear in the question what you are trying to achieve or what is the desired output, but hopefully you can combine the two pieces.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nickthefreak. I now understood what wrong i have done. Actually i wanted to remove the ar[0] value in the whole list. But i didn't think of the for loop val variable. I thought that ' for val in ar: ' it will check whether there is val value in ar or not. I didn't think of the for loop mechanism. Anyway thanks for ur support in helping me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you can print the type of `ar`:

```
print(typee(ar)) # --> output : <class 'list'>
```

So the code `ar.remove(val)` removes the element `ar[0]` as

```
val = ar[0]
```

This gives the answer on why the value of `val` gets changed for each iteration.

Comment: Thnks @Sanip. But why does it gets iterated to the nxt index. In program there is no part to move to the next index...

Comment: There is no change in indexing but using `ar.remove(val)` removes the element of index 0 and now the `element of index 1` becomes the `0 index element`.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote your for function you need to make sure these conditons do not change.
Let us look what happens:
Your input was `30, 20, 10, 10, 20, 50, 10, 20`

`val=ar[0]` which is 30
then it goes to for loop

`ar.remove(val)` removes the first val element so it becomes

```
20, 10, 10, 20, 50, 10, 20
```

However val element will be new `ar[1]` which is 10

Here is the overview of your arrays

> **30**, 20, 10, 10, 20, 50, 10, 20
>
> 20, **10**, 10, 20, 50, 10, 20
>
> 20, 10, **20**, 50, 10, 20
>
> 10, 20, 50, **10**, 20

so it exists from the for loop

Comment: Yaa...thanks @muhammad samadzade..but i couldn't understand why thr val variable is incrementing to the next index.There is no such line that is pointing to the next index.I have given val=ar[0] then it should be the same value only...